# text to find and replace in all files and in all directories

Tags: text-processing, perl

I want to replace all occurrences of `1800 102 6022` with `1860 266 2666` in all files. I have different files in different directories which can contain `1800 102 6022`.

I am using:

```
perl -pi.13.04.2016 -w -e "s/\b1800 102 6022\b/1860 266 2666/g;" /*.jsp
```

which works for a single folder. I want to run this in the parent directory and apply it to all files.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. Please use the [formatting tools](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to make your question easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

Use find command to do that,

```
find /xxx -name '*.jsp' -exec perl -pi.13.04.2016 -w -e "s/\b1800 102 6022\b/1860 266 2666/g;" {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways of doing this:

1. Use `find`:

   ```
   find . -type f -name "*.jsp" \ 
     -exec perl -pi.13.04.2016 -w -e "s/\b1800 102 6022\b/1860 266 2666/g;" {} \;
   ```
2. If you're using `bash`, use `extglob`:

   ```
   shopt -s globstar 
   perl -pi.13.04.2016 -w -e "s/\b1800 102 6022\b/1860 266 2666/g;" **/*jsp
   ```
3. Do the whole thing in Perl, iterating over the files in the directory but that's not really worth the effort here.